# Detect 32 or 64 bits architecture from .exe file programmatically on Windows and C++

Tags: windows, executable, cpu-architecture

Does anyone know how to find out what is the processor architecture (x86 or x64) of .exe file programmatically without executing it?

I have been trying to find a way and the only way i can find is running it and analyzing it at runtime but i need to know the architecture prior to running it, is it possible?

Comment: Read [PE format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx) description.

Comment: As per @Matt read the COFF File Header and look at the Machine field and compare that value against the list of Machine Types https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms680547(v=vs.85).aspx#machine_types and see as well the Characteristics field which "contains flags that indicate attributes of the object or image file."

Comment: By the way, if you  could update your posting with an answer with a source code example, we would all appreciate it.

Comment: Dumpbin.exe /headers tells you the value of the Machine field.